# Why is Dir.glob only evaluate the last file in loop

Tags: ruby

I am trying to write a file search utility in ruby that takes a list of file names found in a txt file and searches my whole computer for these files.  If one of these files is found then the file will be moved to a different directory (effectively deleting it from the directory it was found).

The search has to go through all the folders top down. Thus far I have the following code:

```ruby
File.open("sample-file-list.txt") do |name|  # open file with 
    name.each_line do |file_name|
        puts "here is the file I want to look for: #{file_name}"

        folder = "/Users/bob/code/find-file"
        Dir.glob("#{folder}/**/#{file_name}") do |file|
            puts "now I am working on #{file}"
        end
    end
end
```

The sample-file-list.txt file has these entries:

```
0001.txt
0002.txt
```

Inside the folder above I have the file named "0001.txt". I also have a subfolder in the folder called subdir which contains the file named "0002.txt".

When I run the ruby file in terminal the results I get are:

```
here is the file I want to look for: 0001.txt
here is the file I want to look for: 0002.txt
now I am working on /Users/bob/code/find-file/subdir/0002.txt
```

My code only finds puts the last file in the 0002.txt.  But its seems to skip the 0001.txt file for some reason.

As a side note I rather not use `Dir.glob` as it will be a lot of files but `Dir.each` does not go through subdirectories at least I cannot seem to get it to - but that is another issue.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Indentation is important to understanding, especially at a glance. Do try and keep your code in questions as organized as possible to avoid ambiguity or confusion.

Comment: If you're having performance problems it might be best to `Dir.glob("**/*")` once to fetch everything, then use `grep` to find files in that list.

Comment: I will be more careful in the future.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aside the file name you are looking for, each line of the file you read also contains a newline, assumingly `\n`. This gets included in the string you get from `each_line`.

So the answer is:

1) Use `file_name.strip` as search term so any extra whitespace that is not actually part of the desired file name gets trimmed out. Otherwise `Dir.glob` will fail as it will search for a file / pattern with newline character in the end.

2) The last file in your test case is found, because you don't have a newline in the end of the file. If you add one (ie. the last line of the file is empty), the script will not find even the last actual file in the list.

Comment: thank you for the answer.  adding file_name.strip worked. Now onto the rest of the utility.